# Pull image from website into excel using cell data as part of the URL

Tags: excel

I have a website that has numerous book cover images which match their book number, and print format (hard cover, paperback etc). Using the two values in Excel, is it possible to pull the images from my website automatically?

The Cell value in A1 is ABC123 and cell value in B1 is paperback. I'd like the image to appear in C1 using the following: http://www.example.com/images/ABC123_paperback.jpg

The call needs to be for multiple cells, So A1 + B1, A2 + B2, A3 + B3.

I do not have any experience with Excel so I can't even being to start the formula/VB required! But any reference points to start off would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be able to be accomplished using an WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest in VBA, which you could use to stream the image data to a file and then insert the picture into the Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample VBA code to get you started with downloading a file in Excel.

```
Private Function SaveTo(mURL As String, mDest As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim FileData() As Byte
    Dim Error, Username As String
    Dim WHTTP As Object
    Username = Environ$("Username")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    FileNum = FreeFile
    WHTTP.Open "GET", mURL, False
    WHTTP.SetAutoLogonPolicy (0)
    i = WHTTP.SetTimeouts(2000, 60000, 300000, 300000)
    WHTTP.Send

    If (WHTTP.Status <> 200) Then
        mDest = mDest + "-Error.html"
        Error = Error + "Error " & WHTTP.Status & ":" + Chr(13) + Chr(10)
        Error = Error + WHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders()
        Error = Error + "<b>" + WHTTP.StatusText + "</b>"
        Error = Error + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + "URL: <a href=""" + mURL + """>" + mURL + "</a>"
        Error = Error + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + "Check parameters specified are correct."
        Error = Replace(Error, Chr(13) + Chr(10), "<br/>")
        If (Len(WHTTP.ResponseText) > 0) Then Error = Error + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + WHTTP.ResponseText

        FileData = Error
    Else
        ' We got the file!
        ' Check to see if we had an error downloading last time, and delete the error file
        If (Dir(mDest + "-Error.html") <> "") Then Kill mDest + "-Error.html"

        FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody

    End If

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open mDest For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
    Close #FileNum
    'Debug: Halt on download failure to check syntaxes
    'If (WHTTP.Status <> "200") Then
    '    i = MsgBox("Download Failed! Error: " & WHTTP.Status, vbCritical)
    'End If

    Set WHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```